# How do I copy a table if a specific condition is met?

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement

I can determine whether a condition is met by using the following:

```
SELECT id FROM admin WHERE firstname='John' INTO @tmp
SELECT IF (@tmp >= 1, "success", "fail")
```

But how would I create a copy of the table if the same condition is met?
eg.

```
CREATE TABLE admin_copy LIKE admin
INSERT admin_copy
SELECT * FROM admin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you.

```
SET @create_table := IF(@tmp >= 1, 'CREATE TABLE admin_copy LIKE admin', 'SELECT 0')
;
PREPARE stmt_create FROM @create_table
;
EXECUTE stmt_create
;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_create
;
```